# Map queue/broker contents to tasks

Tags: celery, celery-task

Is there any way to map the content of messages in the broker/queue to a certain task? I am using SQS and celery for a worker architecture and my workers have python tasks/functions. What I want to do is invoke a task according to the content of the message. For example, if my worker has these tasks defined:

```
@celery.task
def add(message):
    pass

@celery.task
def subtract(message):
    pass
```

Then if the message in SQS queue has {"operation":"add"} then "add" task should be invoked and if message has {"operation":"subtract"} then "subtract task should be invoked"

Answer (score 0):

Celery does not consume arbitrary SQS messages. You have to use properly configured Celery instance and apply_async(), delay() or send_task() methods to send *valid* Celery message to a SQS queue.